# TanStack Table ver8 Sorting on each click

Tags: sorting, react-table-v8

I am using TanStack Table ver8.
I have the sorting working, however it appears there are 3 states

Click > sorting -> 'asc'
Click > sorting -> 'des'
Click > sorting -> No sorting
.. repeat

I am trying to get the sorting beavior to be:
Click > sorting -> 'asc'
Click > sorting -> 'des'
Click > sorting -> 'asc'
.. repeat

How can I get the sorting to sort on every click?

I see in the docs column-ordering > resetcolumnorder but how do I use it.

```
const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      sorting,
    },
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    debugTable: true,
  });

  <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
        <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
          {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
            <th key={header.id}>
              {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                <div
                  {...{
                    className: header.column.getCanSort()
                      ? "cursor-pointer select-none"
                      : "",
                    onClick: header.column.getToggleSortingHandler(),
                  }}
                >
                  {flexRender(
                    header.column.columnDef.header,
                    header.getContext()
                  )}
                  {{
                    asc: (
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-up opacity-25 ps-1"></i>
                    ),
                    desc: (
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down opacity-25 ps-1"></i>
                    ),
                  }[header.column.getIsSorted() as string] ?? (
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-up opacity-25 ps-1"></i>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
        <tr key={row.id}>
          {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
            <td key={cell.id}>
              {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

ver8 this has changed to : enableSortingRemoval
https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/sorting#enablesortingremoval

```
const table = useReactTable({
... 
... 
enableSortingRemoval: false,
})
```

ver 7:

[Make react-table sort only between ascending and descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237143/make-react-table-sort-only-between-ascending-and-descending-order)

```
 const table = useReactTable({
{
  .....
  disableSortRemove: true,
  defaultCanSort: true,
```